# Specify order of bars in a bar chart?

Tags: charts

I have a bar chart where I need to specify the order of the bars, and I can't seem to figure out how to do it. I've searched the documentation and Google, but I'm not coming up with anything helpful. Here's my code and the output:

```
BarChart[Counts[mathDataSet[All, "level"]], 
 PlotLabel -> Style["Math Placement", Bold, 20], 
 ChartLabels -> Automatic]
```

[image]

I need them to be in the order of 3 levels below, 2 levels below, 1 level below, college level 1, college level 2, college level 3. I feel like I'm missing something that should be so simple here.

Comment: What is `Counts[mathDataSet[All, "level"]]` ... ? Is it not plotting in the order that you give it?

Comment: @Szabolcs Thank you, that did it!